How to upate service worker precachinng revision value using dynmically generated timestamps?
I am building service worker caching mechanism for my WordPress themes.
Here is how it works.
On initial request service-worker I precache given pages using, these pages fetched using fetchSavedJson function from this /wp-content/saved-posts.json which are constantly updated on backend side using save_post action to save-posts.json which are then is cached by precacheAndRoute inside server worker's install event where all of the revitions are fetched from initial saved-posts.json. These keys have key that starts with the route and has a GET parameter __WB_REVISION__ that contains the revision number.
saved-posts.json:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "url": "\/",
            "revision": "1716314366"
        },
    ]
}

When saved-posts.json is updated, it should trigger cache busting for given route, but I am not sure how to bust cache for keys and values that are created by precacheAndRoute function.
I have already tried deleting the value under the key that is generated by precacheAndRoute function, but than service worker attempts to request old key from the cache, doesn't find it and serve it from network request, while ignore the new cache create manually.
Is my only way to create separate request handler to fully controller the caching mechanism, or I still can bust the cache somehow and replace its values with new ones for the clients?
my service-worker.js:
import * as googleAnalytics from 'workbox-google-analytics'
import {setCacheNameDetails, skipWaiting, clientsClaim} from 'workbox-core'
import {registerRoute, setDefaultHandler} from 'workbox-routing'
import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching'
import {StaleWhileRevalidate, CacheFirst} from 'workbox-strategies'
import {ExpirationPlugin} from 'workbox-expiration'
import {CacheableResponsePlugin} from 'workbox-cacheable-response'

const VERSION = "1.1"
const PREFIX = 'sw'
const JSON_URL = '/wp-content/saved-posts.json'

const HOUR_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60
const DAY_IN_SECONDS = 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS
const WEEK_IN_SECONDS = DAY_IN_SECONDS * 7
const YEAR_IN_SECONDS = DAY_IN_SECONDS * 365
const MONTH_IN_SECONDS = Math.round(YEAR_IN_SECONDS / 12)

const IGNORE_GLOBALS = [
    '/admin',
    '/wp-admin/',
    '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    '/wp-login.php',
]
const IGNORE_CACHES = [
    'google-fonts-stylesheets',
    'google-fonts-webfonts',
]

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    console.log('sw-src.js: install')
    event.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            await clearCache()
        })().catch(error => {
            console.error('Failed to fetch and cache saved posts:', error)
        })
    )
})

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    console.log('sw-src.js: activate')
})

self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
    if (event.data.type === 'LOAD') {
        await compareAndUpdateCache()
        await self.skipWaiting()
        const clients = await self.clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true})
        clients.forEach(client => client.postMessage({type: 'NEW_VERSION_READY'}))
    }

    if (event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
        await self.skipWaiting()
    }

    if (event.data.type === 'CLEAR_OLD_CACHE') {
        await clearCache()
    }
})


async function fetchSavedJson() {
    const response = await fetch(JSON_URL, {cache: "no-store"})
    const json = await response.json()
    return json.data
}

async function getCurrentUrlTimestamp(url, savedPosts) {
    const urlObj = new URL(url)
    const post = savedPosts.find(item => item.url === urlObj.pathname)
    if (post) {
        return post.revision
    }
    return false
}

async function updateCacheValues(cacheName = null, savedPosts) {
    console.log("sw-src.js: updateCacheValues")
    if (cacheName === null) return false
    const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
    const keys = await cache.keys()

    for (const key of keys) {
        try {
            const url = new URL(key.url)
            const cacheRevision = url.searchParams.get('__WB_REVISION__')
            const currentRevision = await getCurrentUrlTimestamp(key.url, savedPosts)

            if (currentRevision && currentRevision !== cacheRevision) {
                url.searchParams.set('__WB_REVISION__', currentRevision)
                const response = await fetch(url, {cache: "no-cache"})

                if (response.ok) {
                    await cache.put(key, response)
                } else {
                    console.error(`Failed to fetch ${key.url} for updating cache`)
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error updating cache for ${key.url}:`, error)
        }
    }
}

async function clearCache() {
    console.log("sw-src.js: clearCache")
    const cacheNames = await caches.keys()
    const savedPosts = await fetchSavedJson()
    for (const cacheName of cacheNames) {
        if (cacheName.includes('precache')) {
            updateCacheValues(cacheName, savedPosts)
        } else if (!IGNORE_CACHES.includes(cacheName)) {
            await caches.delete(cacheName)
        }
    }
}
async function compareAndUpdateCache() {
    console.log("sw-src.js: compareAndUpdateCache")
    const savedPosts = await fetchSavedJson()
    // console.log(savedPosts[0].revision)

    const keys = await caches.keys()
    const cacheNames = keys.filter(key => key.includes('precache'))
    if (cacheNames.length) {
        const cacheName = cacheNames[0]
        updateCacheValues(cacheName, savedPosts)
    }
}

registerRoute(
    ({request}) => request.destination === 'script' || request.destination === 'style',
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: 'static'})
)

registerRoute(
    ({request}) => request.destination === 'image',
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "images",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({maxEntries: 60, maxAgeSeconds: WEEK_IN_SECONDS}),
        ],
    })
)

registerRoute(
    ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://fonts.googleapis.com',
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: `google-fonts-stylesheets`})
)

registerRoute(
    ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: `google-fonts-webfonts`,
        plugins: [
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({statuses: [0, 200]}),
            new ExpirationPlugin({maxAgeSeconds: YEAR_IN_SECONDS, maxEntries: 30}),
        ],
    })
)

googleAnalytics.initialize()
setCacheNameDetails({
    prefix: `${PREFIX}`,
    suffix: `v${VERSION}`,
    precache: 'precache',
    runtime: 'runtime',
    googleAnalytics: 'ga',
})

fetchSavedJson().then(savedPosts => {
    const urlsToCache = savedPosts.map(post => ({
        url: post.url,
        revision: post.revision,
    }))
    precacheAndRoute(urlsToCache)

})

setDefaultHandler(new StaleWhileRevalidate())
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)
skipWaiting()
clientsClaim()


I have solved the problem by moving the login into the fetch here is my solution:
service-worker.js
import * as googleAnalytics from 'workbox-google-analytics'
import {setCacheNameDetails, skipWaiting, clientsClaim} from 'workbox-core'
import {registerRoute, setDefaultHandler} from 'workbox-routing'
import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching'
import {StaleWhileRevalidate, CacheFirst} from 'workbox-strategies'
import {ExpirationPlugin} from 'workbox-expiration'
import {CacheableResponsePlugin} from 'workbox-cacheable-response'
import {method, times} from 'lodash'

const VERSION = "1.1"
const PREFIX = 'sw'
const JSON_URL = '/wp-content/saved-posts.json'

const HOUR_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60
const DAY_IN_SECONDS = 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS
const WEEK_IN_SECONDS = DAY_IN_SECONDS * 7
const YEAR_IN_SECONDS = DAY_IN_SECONDS * 365
const MONTH_IN_SECONDS = Math.round(YEAR_IN_SECONDS / 12)

const IGNORE_GLOBALS = [
    '/admin',
    '/wp-admin/',
    '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    '/wp-login.php',
]
const IGNORE_CACHES = [
    'google-fonts-stylesheets',
    'google-fonts-webfonts',
]

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    log("install")
    event.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            await clearCache()
        })().catch(error => {
            log('Failed to fetch and cache saved posts:', error)
        })
    )
})


self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    log('activate')
})

self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
    if (event.data.type === 'INIT') {
        const cache = await caches.open("current-timestamps")
        const response = await fetch(JSON_URL, {cache: "no-store"})
        await cache.add(JSON_URL, response)
    }

    if (event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
        await self.skipWaiting()
    }

    if (event.data.type === 'CLEAR_OLD_CACHE') {
        await clearCache()
    }
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
    event.respondWith(cacheFirst(event.request))
})


const cacheFirst = async (request) => {
    const requestURL = new URL(request.url)
    const requestPathname = requestURL.pathname
    const preCache = await caches.open(getPrecacheKey())
    const items = await preCacheItems(preCache)

    if (items.has(requestPathname)) {
        const timestamps = await fetchTimestamps()
        const cacheRevision = items.get(requestPathname)
        const currentRevision = timestamps.get(requestPathname)

        if (cacheRevision !== currentRevision) {
            const oldKey = `${requestPathname}?__WB_REVISION__=${cacheRevision}`
            preCache.delete(oldKey)
            const newKey = `${requestPathname}?__WB_REVISION__=${currentRevision}`

            const response = await fetch(request)
            await preCache.put(newKey, response.clone())
            return response
        } else {
            const key = `${requestPathname}?__WB_REVISION__=${cacheRevision}`
            const cachedResponse = await preCache.match(key)
            if (cachedResponse) {
                return cachedResponse
            }
        }
    }

    return fetch(request)
}
async function preCacheItems(preCache) {
    const output = new Map

    for (const key of await preCache.keys()) {
        const url = new URL(key.url)
        const revision = url.searchParams.get('__WB_REVISION__')
        if (revision) {
            output.set(url.pathname, revision)
        }
    }

    return output
}


function log(message, error = null) {
    console.log('sw-src.js: ' + message)
    if (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}

async function fetchTimestamps() {
    const cache = await caches.open("current-timestamps")
    let response = await cache.match(JSON_URL)
    if (!response) {
        response = await fetch(JSON_URL, {cache: "no-store"})
        cache.put(JSON_URL, response.clone())
    }
    const {data} = await response.json()

    const output = new Map
    for (const item of data) {
        output.set(item.url, item.revision)
    }

    return output
}

// Function
function getPrecacheKey() {
    return `${PREFIX}-precache-v${VERSION}`
}

// Async Fuctions
async function clearCache() {
    log("clearing cache")
    const cacheKeys = await caches.keys()
    for (key of cacheKeys) {
        await caches.delete(key)
    }
}

registerRoute(
    ({request}) => request.destination === 'script' || request.destination === 'style',
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: 'static'})
)

registerRoute(
    ({request}) => request.destination === 'image',
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "images",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({maxEntries: 60, maxAgeSeconds: WEEK_IN_SECONDS}),
        ],
    })
)

registerRoute(
    ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://fonts.googleapis.com',
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: `google-fonts-stylesheets`})
)

registerRoute(
    ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: `google-fonts-webfonts`,
        plugins: [
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({statuses: [0, 200]}),
            new ExpirationPlugin({maxAgeSeconds: YEAR_IN_SECONDS, maxEntries: 30}),
        ],
    })
)

setCacheNameDetails({
    prefix: `${PREFIX}`,
    suffix: `v${VERSION}`,
    precache: 'precache',
    runtime: 'runtime',
    googleAnalytics: 'ga',
})

googleAnalytics.initialize()
setDefaultHandler(new StaleWhileRevalidate())

fetchTimestamps().then(timestamps => {
    const urls = []
    for (const key of timestamps.keys()) {
        const revision = timestamps.get(key)
        urls.push({url: key, revision})
    }

    precacheAndRoute(urls)
})

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)

skipWaiting()
clientsClaim()

